# How can I pass a number in the 'neighbor' statement as an offset using CTE in ClickHouse SQL?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I need to pass number of hosts in where clause to "neighbor" statement as offset, but when I run the statement below:

```
WITH (
    SELECT COUNT(distinct hostname)
    FROM data.table
    WHERE timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
      AND hostname IN ('host1', 'host2')
) AS req_hosts
SELECT NEIGHBOR(current_val, req_hosts) AS prev_val,
       (100 - ((current_val - prev_val)/ 60)* 100)
FROM data.table
WHERE hostname IN ('host1', 'host2');
```

I receive error:

> Code: 43. DB::Exception: Illegal type Nullable(UInt64) of second argument of function neighbor - should be an integer: While processing (neighbor(current_val, _CAST(163980, 'Nullable(UInt64)') AS req_hosts) AS prev_val) != 0. (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT)

I tried using toUnIt64() / toInt64() it still says Nullable(Int64) is illegal. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ClickHouse SQL, when using the NEIGHBOR function with a CTE (Common Table Expression) and passing a number as an offset, you need to ensure that the data type is a non-nullable integer type. The error you encountered suggests that the data type Nullable(UInt64) or Nullable(Int64) is not accepted by the NEIGHBOR function.

To resolve this issue, you can use the CAST function to convert the result of the COUNT aggregation to a non-nullable integer type. Here's an updated version of your query:

```html
WITH
(
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(hostname) AS Int64)
    FROM data.table
    WHERE timestamp >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
      AND hostname IN ('host1', 'host2')
) AS req_hosts
SELECT NEIGHBOR(current_val, req_hosts) AS prev_val,
       (100 - ((current_val - prev_val) / 60) * 100)
FROM data.table
WHERE hostname IN ('host1', 'host2');
```

In this example, the CAST function is used to convert the result of COUNT(hostname) to Int64, which is a non-nullable integer type compatible with the NEIGHBOR function.

Comment: It worked when I moved CAST to neightbor: CAST(req_hosts AS Int64)). Thanks.